# Custom CSS Media Query conditions

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I want to change some CSS properties of an element based upon the width of its parent element for responsive design.

For example,

The parent element will have a minimum width of 200px and will stretch to at max 500px regardless of the screen size/width. I want to set a fixed width to its children elements based on the width of its parent container.

I am looking for no Javascript solution for this. +1 if it can be somehow implemented using custom media query.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you saying that the parent object will be full screen width up to 500px, and then max out at that size? I wasnt sure if there was a connection to screen size.

Comment: Yes it shouldn't have any connection to the screen size

Answer (score 2):

Try It Once

```
@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 499px) {
    //styles here    
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1024) {
   //styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use Media query

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 200px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width : 500px) {

}
```